# Get correspondences using Chamfer matching opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, template-matching

I am using chamfer matching to match a template with a reference image. I am using OpenCV'r chamermatching() method. I get the matching scores, but how can I get the correspondences ? In other words, corresponding to each cost, how can I get the template point to reference image point correspondence ? Thanks in advance!

I am using the following code:

```
int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{

Mat img = imread(argv[1], 0);
Mat tpl = imread(argv[2], 0);
GaussianBlur(img, img, cv::Size(3, 3), 4.0);
GaussianBlur(tpl, tpl, cv::Size(3, 3), 4.0);
imshow("Image", img);
imshow("Template", tpl);

if (img.empty() || tpl.empty())
{
    cout << "Could not read image files";
    return -1;
}
Mat cimg;
cvtColor(img, cimg, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

// if the image and the template are not edge maps but normal grayscale images,
// you might want to uncomment the lines below to produce the maps. You can also
// run Sobel instead of Canny.

// Canny(img, img, 5, 50, 3);
// Canny(tpl, tpl, 5, 50, 3);

vector<vector<Point> > results;
vector<float> costs;
int best = chamerMatching( img, tpl, results, costs );
if( best < 0 )
{
    cout << "matching not found" << endl;
    return -1;
}

cout << results.size() << endl;
size_t i, n = results[best].size();
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    Point pt = results[best][i];
    if( pt.inside(Rect(0, 0, cimg.cols, cimg.rows)) )
       cimg.at<Vec3b>(pt) = Vec3b(0, 255, 0);
}

imshow("result", cimg);

float total_cost = 0.0;
for(int i=0;i<costs.size();i++)
    total_cost += costs[i];

cout << total_cost << "\n";


waitKey();

return 0;
```

}